# Is there a way to get Android ID or UUID (Apple) from a rails app?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to track information for an app that will let me customize the experience for my users when they are not logged in.  For this is would like to (if possibly) get my users Android ID or UUID (Apple).  Is there any way to get this information once they are on mobile web?

Comment: On the Android side, any browser that leaks `ANDROID_ID` has a privacy flaw.

Comment: You can't even get the UUID in iOS from a native app, much less will this be accessible from the web.

Comment: Your users need to log-in if you want to customize the experience.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned this isn't something you can do because of privacy concerns.

What you need to do instead is to generate your own uid (see http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html), store it as a cookie on the users machine + in your database. Every time someone comes to your site you can check if they have the cookie, if they do you'll know it's the same user as previous.

When someone clears their cookies or the cookie expires you'll no longer be able to identify that user.